# Not showing image in imageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have the following fragment. No matter what I do but the image is not visible in the Image View-: For testing I put the button on fragment but that is refelected but image is not visible

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.transenigma.iskconapp.DynamicImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/img2"
            android:id="@+id/myAboutImg" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="8dp"
            tools:text="Text"
             />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
    <!--</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>-->

</FrameLayout>
```

I have made the following class that extends ImageView-:

```
package com.transenigma.iskconapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DynamicImageView extends ImageView {

    public DynamicImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final Drawable d = this.getDrawable();

        if (d != null) {
            // ceil not round - avoid thin vertical gaps along the left/right edges
            final int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            final int height = (int) Math.ceil(width * (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight() / d.getIntrinsicWidth());
            this.setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try replacing this `com.transenigma.iskconapp.DynamicImageView` with a normal `ImageView`

Comment: I already tried but no use.

Comment: No matter what I do --- have you tried any other image?? get a png image from the net to be sure is not corrupt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you want to do in your DynamicImageView?
You can try to delete the method onMeasure,and see the difference between them.
Maybe the mistake is in your onMeasure.